# YouTube API getting error when trying to compile

Tags: youtube-api

I am using following code to try and retrieve the list of feeds from the YouTube API in a project that I build with maven.

```
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService("dev","123456");
String feedUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed";
VideoFeed videofeed = service.getFeed(new URL(feedUrl), VideoFeed.class);
List<VideoEntry> videos = videofeed.getEntries();
```

When I do "mvn package" I get following error:

```
found   : com.google.gdata.data.IFeed
required: com.google.gdata.data.youtube.VideoFeed
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong?
My import looks like this:

```
import com.google.gdata.client.youtube.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.extensions.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.mediarss.*;
```

POM file. I added the artifactId using following method:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=youtube-12 -DartifactId=youtube-12 -Dversion=1.47.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/usr/share/gdata/java/lib/gdata-calendar-2.0.jar 

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>youtube-1</groupId>
      <artifactId>youtube-1</artifactId>
      <version>1.47.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>youtube-2</groupId>
      <artifactId>youtube-2</artifactId>
      <version>1.47.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>youtube-3</groupId>
      <artifactId>youtube-3</artifactId>
      <version>1.47.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
     <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
     <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
     <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
     <version>12.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your POM file to analyze the dependencies?